# How to set ServerCredential in Backgrounduploader in WinJS app

Tags: windows-store-apps, winjs, networkcredentials, background-transfer

I called attached code below in WinJS app and keep getting this error 405 Method Not Allowed. I have changed the method property to "POST" , still the same thing. Some of the guys saying it is to do with the permission so I am trying to set the credential in the uploader. This is an internal app so we assume this should carry the Windows Authentication. But at the moment, I could not find how. Can anybody help?

```
uploader.createUpload(endpoint, file)
                    .startAsync()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't narrowed down the problem to the point where you should be worrying about how to express what you need with BackgroundTransfer APIs yet - you need to figure out what you need to express, first.

If you have access to good documentation or a knowledgeable owner of this internal service you're connecting to, your first step should be consulting that to figure out what exactly the HTTP request (and the associated credential headers) should look like.

If you don't have access to that, the second best starting point is to take an existing, working client of this service you're uploading to and use a networking capture software (Fiddler, for example) to take a look at what the request it's sending looks like.

Once you've figured out the specific HTTP method and server credentials you need to use, you can tell BackgroundTransfer to use them by setting the [`method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.backgrounduploader.method.aspx) and [`serverCredential`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.backgrounduploader.servercredential.aspx) properties of your `uploader` object before creating your uploads.

Comment: Hi Dan, Thanks for the feedback. I figured out the BITS is different from Background transfer in Windows 8 app. I was given the wrong information.